# Australian PhD related forums and online Inquiry consultants

Tags: student-visa, australia, study

How to get into the sponsored PhD programs in University of Melbourne or University of Sydney?

I am an Electronics engineering student and have Masters in Photonics (Optical sensing). I have found a professor from UniMelb who has expertise in this field of study and mentors the PhD scholars. How do I approach him *(or any other professor for that matter)*?

Are there any dedicated portals for such queries?

Also, How does one get a sponsored PhD offer?

Comment: If your prospective supervisor works at the University of Melbourne, just apply to them directly: https://study.unimelb.edu.au/find/courses/graduate/doctor-of-philosophy-science/how-to-apply/

Comment: Welcome! You may also want to do some searching at the [academia.se] StackExchange.